# How to abort a thread properly?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm writing a scripting interface for a server emulator for NPC chats. The player can initiate a NPC chat by clicking on the NPC. The NPC can send text dialogs. Those text dialogs also contain a `End Chat` button to end the chat before the script finishes execution, or the player can continue with the text dialogs normally until they end.

When the player interrupts the chat, a special packet is sent.

I've created a class called `WaitableResult` which takes advantage of `ManualResetEvent` to block the current thread until given result and then returns the result:

```
public sealed class WaitableResult<T> where T : struct
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }

    private ManualResetEvent mEvent;

    public WaitableResult()
    {
        mEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    public void Wait()
    {
        mEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    public void Set(T value)
    {
        mEvent.Set();

        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

This is my script classes:

```
internal sealed class NpcScript : ScriptBase
{
    public WaitableResult<bool> BoolResult { get; private set; }

    private Npc mNpc;
    private Player mPlayer;

    public NpcScript(Npc npc, Player player)
        : base(string.Format(@"..\..\scripts\npcs\{0}.lua", npc.Script), true)
    {
        mNpc = npc;
        mPlayer = player;
        mPlayer.NpcConversation = this;

        this.Expose("answer_no", false);
        this.Expose("answer_yes", true);
        this.Expose("answer_decline", false);
        this.Expose("answer_accept", true);

        this.Expose("say", new Func<string, bool>(this.Say));
        this.Expose("askYesNo", new Func<string, bool>(this.AskYesNo));
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();

        mPlayer.NpcConversation = null;
    }

    private bool Say(string text)
    {
        this.BoolResult = new WaitableResult<bool>();

        using (OutPacket outPacket = mNpc.GetDialogPacket(ENpcDialogType.Standard, text, 0, 0))
        {
            mPlayer.Client.SendPacket(outPacket);
        }

        this.BoolResult.Wait();

        return this.BoolResult.Value;
    }

    private bool AskYesNo(string text)
    {
        this.BoolResult = new WaitableResult<bool>();

        using (OutPacket outPacket = mNpc.GetDialogPacket(ENpcDialogType.YesNo, text))
        {
            mPlayer.Client.SendPacket(outPacket);
        }

        this.BoolResult.Wait();

        return this.BoolResult.Value;
    }
}

 public abstract class ScriptBase
{
    private string mPath;
    private Thread mThread;
    private MoonSharp.Interpreter.Script mScript;


    public ScriptBase(string path, bool useThread = false, CoreModules modules = CoreModules.None)
    {
        mPath = path;
        if (useThread) mThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => mScript.DoFile(mPath)));
        mScript = new MoonSharp.Interpreter.Script(modules);
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        if (mThread != null)
        {
            mThread.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            mScript.DoFile(mPath);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (mThread != null)
        {
            mThread.Abort();
            mThread = null;
        }
    }

    protected void Expose(string key, object value)
    {
        mScript.Globals[key] = value;
    }
}
```

And here's an example of a script:

```
say('test')
say('some more stuff')
say('good bye')
```

When a player initiates a chat with a NPC and finishes it without interrupting it (aka closing it using the `End Chat` button), the thread should be aborted by itself (as it finished all it's instructions).

However, when a player aborts the chat before it finishes execution, I'm calling the `Dispose` button to manually abort the thread - but I'm not sure it's the right way to do it.

My memory usage also increases by 1 MB everytime a player starts a chat, so that's also kind of weird.

Comment: You can't really just "kill" a thread like you can a process. The pattern people use is that whatever method is running in the thread needs to continuously check an "abort" flag, if the flag is set then you have the method literally return which stops execution. .NET facilitates this in tasks using `CancelToken`'s, e.g., see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx), you will notice how *every single iteration* the code is checking the cancel token, if it's canceled then it stops executing (in this case by throwing an exception, not by returning).

Comment: As for `Thread.Abort` being bad, [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251964/c-sharp-thread-termination-and-thread-abort): "The only thing that can guarantee safe termination of an uncooperative thread is the operating system taking down its entire process.", which links to [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort/1560567#1560567): "There is no guarantee whatsoever that a call to Thread.Abort will actually abort the thread in question, ever", "In short, Thread.Abort is at best indicative of bad design, possibly unreliable, and extremely dangerous".

Comment: Instead of thinking of it as Aborting think of it as Canceling. Relevent reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Regarding the memory increase you are experiencing, that is one of the inconveniences of manually spawning threads, each thread initializes its own stack space  and on a 32-bit process, the default is precisely 1MB.  There is a Thread constructor overload that allows you to customize the stack size; I'm guessing that for a chat application, this value can be set to a fairly small value without risking a stack overflow condition.

Comment: I think that if you reword your question to something like "How can I cleanly  terminate a Lua script running on a separate thread", you could ask for removal of the Duplicate label that has been given to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As **Quantic** has already addressed, aborting a thread by means of `Thread.Abort` invites unexpected - even dangerous results. **Quantic** also addressed the preferred pattern to deal with a thread, usually the thread loops and checks for a termination flag, which is not possible if you are executing an arbitrary Lua script.

One option you have is to create a minimalistic debugger and attach it to your script. Once this debugger is attached, the `IDebugger.GetAction()` method will be called for every instruction in the running script. **If during the `GetAction()`call you raise an `Exception`, the script will be terminated, cleanly, by the debugger.**

[Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/xanathar/2c777a79937398834ad4) of a sentinel, minimalistic debugger that stops a long-running script using such a technique. As you can see, most of the implementation is empty. In your case, instead of using a running instruction counter, you may simply have a boolean flag that indicates that the script must be terminated.

```
public DebuggerAction GetAction(int ip, SourceRef sourceref)
{
    if( _abortScript )          
       throw new MyException();  // abort cleanly

    // Proceed running the next statement
    return new DebuggerAction() { 
      Action = DebuggerAction.ActionType.StepIn,
    };
}
```

Regarding the memory increase you are experiencing, that is one of the inconveniences of manually spawning threads, [each thread initializes its own stack space and on a 32-bit process, the default is precisely 1MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507574/maximum-thread-stack-size-net). There is a [Thread constructor overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cykbwz4.aspx) that allows you to customize the stack size; Depending on the complexity of the scripts, this value could probably be set to a smaller value without risking a stack overflow condition. Another option to minimize memory usage would be to use a `Task.Run` instead of spawning your own thread (this makes use of the Thread pool), but then refraining from using `Thread.Abort` would be **mandatory**, you don't want to go killing pooled threads!